# NHibernate - Question marks instead of values in query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, nhibernate

Basically I have a `Topic` Object which can have multiple `Category`'s associted with it. I'm trying to insert a new `Category` to a particular `Topic` and I get an error.

Working with `ASP.NET 4` , also with `windows-1255` encoding on the front-end and in `ASP` and `hebrew_bin` on `MySQL` (the back-end)

```
ISession session = dal.GetSession();
using (session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Topic t = session.Get<Topic>(topicId);
    Category c = new Category() { Name=name };
    t.AddCategory(c); // updates both references (inside `t` and inside `c`)
    session.Update(t);
    session.Save(c);
    session.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

Getting Error:

> could not insert: [DAL.Models.Category#1][SQL: INSERT INTO Category (Name, Publish, TopicID, ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]

Ultimately it fails because of a foreign key constraint violation (I guess `?` is not a valid `ID`):

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`etladaatdb`.`category`, CONSTRAINT `FK6482F249B6E2851` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `topic` (`ID`))

Topic.cs:

```
public enum ColorEnum { Blue, Red, Green, Yellow }
    public class Topic
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual string ImageUri { get; set; }
        public virtual ColorEnum Color { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddCategory(Category c)
        {
            Categories.Add(c);
            c.Topic = this;
        }
    }
```

Topic.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="DAL"
                   namespace="DAL.Models">
  <class name="Topic" lazy="true">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Description" />
    <property name="ImageUri" />
    <property name="Color" type="ColorEnum" />

    <bag name="Categories" lazy="true" inverse="true"
                         batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ID" />
      <one-to-many class="Category" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Category.cs:

```
public class Category
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Publish { get; set; }

        public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
    }
```

Category.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="DAL"
                   namespace="DAL.Models">
  <class name="Category" lazy="true">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"/>
    <property name="Publish" />

    <many-to-one name="Topic" class="Topic" column="TopicID" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really seems, that you've just missed to assign topic to category. So this should do that trick:

```
// original
Category c = new Category() { Name=name };
t.AddCategory(c);
// always assign both sides during creation
c.Topic = t;
```

Now NHibernate will know what is the referenced **`Topic`** ... and will insert proper **`ID`**

About mapping. The relation many-to-one and one-to-many is expressed by exactly one column. It is the foreign key column in child (categories) table - **`TopicID`**.

So this is the correct mapping:

```
// Topic
<bag name="Categories" lazy="true" inverse="true"
                     batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  // this is wrong
  // <key column="ID" />
  // this is the target column in the other table
  <key column="TopicID" />
  <one-to-many class="Category" />
</bag>

...

// Category
// the same columns for the same relation
<many-to-one name="Topic" class="Topic" column="TopicID" />
```

Having cascade in place, we can just save the topic:

```
session.Update(t);
// not needed, there is a cascade
// session.Save(c);
```

Comment: Observed the mapping and found one issue. Relation is about one column for both sides...

Comment: Check my answer - the bag mapping would require `<key column="TopicID" />` not the original `<key column="ID" />`

Comment: Amazing, enjoy mighty NHibernate, sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your entity is not complete and you should change your code.
Do not forget to use a `using` statement for `IDisposable` objects.

```
using(ISession session = dal.GetSession())
{
using (session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Topic t = session.Get<Topic>(topicId);
    Category c = new Category() { Name=name };
    t.AddCategory(c);
    c.Topic = t;
    session.SaveOrUpdate(t);
    session.Transaction.Commit();
}
}
```

You could also inside your `t.AddCategory(c);` method:

```
public void AddCategory(Category category)
{
  // add to list
  category.Topic = this;
}
```